# How-to Un-Join Domain when DC not available on Win 2008 R2 Core Installation Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Server was moved and domain contraller not available any more. Is it a way to disjoin Domain on Win 2008 R2 Core Installation Hyper-V?

Answer (score 3):

Is the server a Domain Controller?  If not, I believe you can just put the server in workgroup mode and delete the computer account from the domain.  Someone correct me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yep, switch it to a workgroup (might have to use the force option). Then delete the account from the domain.

Answer (score 2):

You should of course be aware of the excellent core utilities which makes all this a bit simpler for us command line impaired.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/guyt/archive/2008/03/22/windows-server-core-coreconfigurator-to-the-rescue.aspx

http://www.smart-x.com/?CategoryID=198&ArticleID=170&sng=1

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this exact issue when trying to disconnect a copied VM from another network.  The DC from the previous environment wasn't available in the new location and my VM was also a Win2008R2 Core installation.  Under the same conditions, the GUI domain/workgroup tools in Computer Properties would have disconnected it from the domain.

I was using the domain GUI tool from CoreConfig and got this error, and also got it from netdom.  Adding in the /force option in netdom was the fix.  The GUI tools from a full installation of Windows apparently take care of this automatically.

netdom remove /d:mydomain mywksta /ud:mydomain\admin /pd:password **/force**